# Get main term from a sub term in Woocommerce

Tags: custom-taxonomy, plugins

I need to show

- MAIN term

  - sub term 1
  - sub term 2
  - …

Every time I click on sub term. I mean, I don't want to show the other MAIN terms, just the one I select with the sub terms.

In `woocommerce-template.php` I use:

```
function woocommerce_content() {

    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

        <div class="three columns alpha">
            <div id="menu_commerce">
            <?php 
                    global $post;

                    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ){
                    $category_id = $term->term_id;
                    $category_name = $term->name;
                    $category_slug = $term->slug;
                    echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link($term->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'.$category_name.'</a></li>';

                    }?>

            </div><!--END MENU COMMERCE-->
        </div><!--END 3 COLUMNS ALPHA-->

        <div class="thirteen columns alpha">

        <?php   woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );?>

        </div>

        <?php endwhile;

    } else {

        ?>

        <div class="three columns alpha">
            <div id="menu_commerce">
            <?php 

                global $wp_query;
                // get the query object
                $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
                if($cat_obj)    {
                    $category_name = $cat_obj->name;
                    $category_desc = $cat_obj->description;
                    $category_ID  = $cat_obj->term_id;
                    $category_slug = $cat_obj->slug;
                }
                woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($category_ID)

                ?>
            </div><!--END MENU COMMERCE-->
        </div><!--END 3 COLUMNS ALPHA-->

        <div class="thirteen columns alpha">

        <div id="prod_titolo"><h1><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1></div>
        <hr style="margin-bottom:20px"/>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop'); ?>

            <div id="menu_grid">

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="four columns">

                    <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                    </div><!--END 4 col-->

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
            </div><!--END menu grid-->
```

It works for single product, but if I click on a sub term, the MAIN disappears.

The function I use in `functions.php` is:

```
function woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($parent_cat_ID) {
$args = array(
   'hierarchical' => 1,
   'show_option_none' => '',
   'hide_empty' => 0,
   'parent' => $parent_cat_ID,
   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
);
$subcats = get_categories($args);
echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist">';

  foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
    $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
      echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
  }
echo '</ul>';
```

}

Can you help me please?

Comment: just to clarify, you want to output the main-category (toplevel) on the sub-category archive pages, right?

Comment: yes! can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### code

```
function wc_origin_trail_ancestor( $link = false, $trail = false ) {

    if (is_product_category()) {
        global $wp_query;
        $q_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $cat_id = $q_obj->term_id;

        $descendant = get_term_by("id", $cat_id, "product_cat");
        $descendant_id = $descendant->term_id;

        $ancestors = get_ancestors($cat_id, 'product_cat');
        $ancestors = array_reverse($ancestors);

        $origin_ancestor = get_term_by("id", $ancestors[0], "product_cat");
        $origin_ancestor_id = $origin_ancestor->term_id;

        $ac = count($ancestors);

    } else if ( is_product() ) {

        $ancestors = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

        $i = 0;
        foreach($ancestors as $ancestor) {
            if( $i == 0 ) {
                $origin_ancestor = $ancestor;
                $origin_ancestor_id = $origin_ancestor->term_id;
            }
        }

        $ancestors = array_reverse($ancestors);

        $ac = count($ancestors);

        $descendant = $ancestors[0];
        $descendant_id = $descendant->term_id;

        $ancestors = array_reverse(get_ancestors($descendant_id, 'product_cat'));

    }


    $c = 1;
    if( $trail == false ){

        $origin_ancestor_term = get_term_by("id", $origin_ancestor_id, "product_cat");
        $origin_ancestor_link = get_term_link( $origin_ancestor_term->slug, $origin_ancestor_term->taxonomy );

        if($link == true) 
            echo '<a href="'. $origin_ancestor_link .'">';
        echo $origin_ancestor->name;
        if($link == true) 
            echo '</a>';

    }else{

        foreach ($ancestors as $ancestor) {
            $ancestor_term = get_term_by("id", $ancestor, "product_cat");
            $ancestor_link = get_term_link( $ancestor_term->slug, $ancestor_term->taxonomy );

            if($c++ == 1) 
                echo '» '; 
            else if($c++ != 1 || $c++ != $ac) 
                echo ' » ';

            if($link == true) 
                echo '<a href="'. $ancestor_link .'">';
            echo  $ancestor_term->name;
            if($link == true) 
                echo '</a>';

        }

        $descendant_term = get_term_by("id", $descendant_id, "product_cat");
        $descendant_link = get_term_link( $descendant_term->slug, $descendant_term->taxonomy );

        echo ' » ';
        if($link == true) 
            echo '<a href="'. $descendant_link .'">';
        echo $descendant->name;
        if($link == true) 
            echo '</a>';

    }

}
```

#### how to use

- just toplevel, origin ancestor; without link
  `wc_origin_trail_ancestor();`
- just toplevel, origin ancestor; with link
  `wc_origin_trail_ancestor(true);`
- ancestor trail; without link
  `wc_origin_trail_ancestor(false,true);`
- ancestor trail; with link
  `wc_origin_trail_ancestor(true,true);`

#### notes

- won't work if a product has multiple main-/toplevel-categories, or at least won't show them all;
- same should be the case for multiple subcategories on the same level;
- I did no further tests concerning above points, because the function does all I wanted for that project;

Comment: wow! great! it's perfect!
thanks a lot!
I hope to help you some day as you've done with me!
thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad i could help! Maybe you can help me sometime or just help somebody else!