# Reverse traversing taxonomy based on term_id

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Is it possible to do a reversed traversing up the hierarchy, if a child term id is known?

For example, I might have a taxonomy that looks like this:

```
Cars
   - Pink
   - Blue
   - Grey
   - Silver
       - Metallic
       - Matte
       - Unpolished
            - Clear Vinyl
```

I have the id for 'Clear Vinyl', now what I want to do is build a view of all the parents, all the way up to cars.

I can get the top-most parent ID, from which I can 'infer' where to stop the traversal down, until I hit the ID for 'Clear Vinyl', but this seems like such a tedious job. Is there no why that I can say 'give me all parents for term_id = x'.

Comment: I have given an [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101413/22534) an how to get all ancestors of a sub term a while ago. It should help you to do what you want, it is about woocommerce, but pretty much all you have to do is replace `product_cat` with your custom taxonomy and remove the woocommerce specific conditional tags.

Comment: You, my friend @ialocin, deserve a bells! thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. Do me a favor and either come back and post your working code as an answer or delete the question if you not longer need an answer or if you are having trouble add the code you are working on to the question. If the latter is the case, then ping me and I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @ialocin in his comment above, I took his [recommendation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101389/get-main-term-from-a-sub-term-in-woocommerce/101413#101413) and adapted it to fit my needs. Traversing the taxonomy hierarchy from the bottom up is actually relatively simple if you understand how WordPress does this from the top down.

```
function origin_trail_ancestor($cat_id = 0, $link = false, $trail = false) {

    global $wp_query;

    $anchor = "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>";
    $html = '';

    $descendant = get_term_by('id', $cat_id, 'taxonomy');
    $descendant_id = $descendant->term_id;

    $ancestors = get_ancestors($cat_id, 'taxonomy');
    $ancestors = array_reverse($ancestors);

    $origin_ancestor = get_term_by('id', $ancestors[0], 'taxonomy');
    $origin_ancestor_id = $origin_ancestor->term_id;

    $ac = count($ancestors);

    $c = 1;

    if ($trail == false) {
        $origin_ancestor_term = get_term_by('id', $origin_ancestor_id, 'taxonomy');
        $origin_ancestor_link = get_term_link($origin_ancestor_term->slug, $origin_ancestor_term->taxonomy);

        if ($link == true) {
            $html .= sprintf($anchor, $origin_ancestor_link, $origin_ancestor->name);
        }
    }
    else {

        foreach ($ancestors as $ancestor) {
            $ancestor_term = get_term_by('id', $ancestor, 'taxonomy');
            $ancestor_link = get_term_link($ancestor_term->slug, $ancestor_term->taxonomy);

            if ($c++ == 1) {
                $html .= '';
            }
            else if ($c++ != 1 || $c++ != $ac) {
                $html .= ' / ';
            }

            if ($link == true) {
                $html .= sprintf($anchor, $ancestor_link, $ancestor_term->name);
            }
        }

        $descendant_term = get_term_by('id', $descendant_id, 'taxonomy');
        $descendant_link = get_term_link( $descendant_term->slug, $descendant_term->taxonomy );

        $html .= ' / ';

        $anchor = "<strong>%s</strong>";

        if ($link == true) {
            $html .= sprintf($anchor, $descendant_term->name);
        }
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Which can then be used to do something like:

```
$breadcrumb = sprintf('<strong>You are here:</strong> %s / %s', '<a href="' . site_url('/suppliers/') . '">All Suppliers</a>', origin_trail_ancestor($main_listing_id, true, true));
```

Where `$main_listing_id` is the id of the current taxonomy ID the user is browsing and you would want to traverse back from.

Thanks bud.